# Error 404 mvc- area rooting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a problem with an asp.Net project. I have changed some things in my client. At first the register view was inside the account view by default but i wanted to change that because i did other changes in the code too. Now when i run it can't find the path(error 404) .I changed the view by clicking at my register controler => add view. I have read other posts about the mvc areas but i can't unterstant exactly what i need to change because i am a newbie. I tried that code. My controller name is register my method ActionResult is also register().

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        "Register", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Register", action = "Register", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: on requesting what url are you getting the 404 ?

Comment: when i launch my whole program at my browser everithing is ok but when i go to the navigation bar and click register j get the error.

Comment: what url is it trying to reach ?

Comment: What is the URL you are seeing in the browser?

Comment: http://localhost:59436/Account/Register because that was the old root

Comment: @Black_mamba You need to update your calls to old method. See the answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Register` action method exists in the `RegisterController` now, not `AccountController`. So you need to update the calls to your old register action method (`Account/Register`) to the new one (`Register/Register`), in your layout / other views files

Change

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account")
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Register")
```

This will generate Link with href value set to `"Register/Register"` which is a valid request for an existing route.

Comment: You are welcome ! Welcome to the magic world of ASP.NET MVC :)

Answer (score 0):

The bit of code you referenced is exactly the same as the default rule, except that if you enter a url with no path it will assume it should use a controller named `Register` using an action named `Register`. It will actually overwrite your default rule if it is placed first because all possible URLs match the URL pattern.

- localhost:59436
- localhost:59436/Register
- localhost:59436/Register/Register

These all point to the same thing using your Routing rule. I'm not sure that is what you intended.

What is the name of the controller and action you are using to register? You need to update your links to use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "ActionName", "ControllerName")
```